# Kill All Processes Spawned by NPM During Shell Script

Tags: shell, flock, bash-trap

I have a shell script that looks roughly like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script variables
NPM="/usr/bin/npm"

# Start several sub-processes in a loop in parallel
for i in {1..4}; do
    $NPM run -s long_running_script >> /path/to/script/output/stream.tsv &
done
wait
```

To ensure that the long-running script is continuously running, but to prevent multiple instances in parallel, I invoke it via cron using:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /var/lock/my_lock_file /path/to/script/hourly.sh
```

I have tried using trap and adding this to the beggining of the script, but no luck:

```
trap "kill $(jobs -p)" EXIT
```

Different variations of the above didn't work either, like `trap "kill -HUP -$$"`. It seems that trap does not even get executed (presumably because it's waiting for all instances of `$NPM run -s long_running_script` to finish?).

I am able to kill the processes from a different script knowing the names of the children and grandchildren and then executing `pkill`, but I would much prefer a more generic solution. Is there a way to kill all processes spawned from a shell script without manually keeping track of all spawned processes and their subsequent children?

#### Update

Added more details to the script snippet to show that I'm piping the output. Here is a snapshot of the processes being spawned by NPM (in each of the loop's iterations):

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      4124  4122 10 14:51 ?        00:00:01 npm
root      4134  4124  0 14:51 ?        00:00:00 sh -c node long_running_script.js
root      4135  4134 42 14:51 ?        00:00:03 node long_running_script.js
```

And the corresponding output from lsof:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
npm     4124 root  cwd       DIR   43,0     4096 2753156 /path/to/working/directory
npm     4124 root  rtd       DIR   43,0     4096       2 /
npm     4124 root  txt       REG   43,0 11187096 1971997 /usr/bin/nodejs
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0 25913104 2238299 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0  1864888 2757931 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0    89696 2752592 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0  1088952 2757928 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0  1566440 2234802 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0  1636360 2238295 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0  2496856 2238296 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55.1
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0  2361856 2752549 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0   428384 2752550 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0    14608 2757925 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0   138696 2757942 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0    31712 2757938 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0   142640 2238078 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1.0.0
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0   104824 2752763 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
npm     4124 root  mem       REG   43,0   162632 2757932 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
npm     4124 root    0r      CHR    1,3      0t0    1031 /dev/null
npm     4124 root    1w      REG   43,0  2488489 2752561 /path/to/script/output/stream.tsv
npm     4124 root    2w      REG   43,0     4669 1837068 /var/log/my_log_file
npm     4124 root    3r      REG   0,17        0    8980 /run/lock/my_lock_file
npm     4124 root    4r     FIFO    0,9      0t0    8092 pipe
npm     4124 root    5w     FIFO    0,9      0t0    8092 pipe
npm     4124 root    6u  a_inode   0,10        0    2049 [eventpoll]
npm     4124 root    7r     FIFO    0,9      0t0    8093 pipe
npm     4124 root    8w     FIFO    0,9      0t0    8093 pipe
npm     4124 root    9u  a_inode   0,10        0    2049 [eventfd]
```

#### Update 2

And here is what happens when I call `fuser -k`, which only kills the top-level process and npm but none of its grandchildren:

```
root@host:/ fuser -v /var/lock/my_file_lock 
/run/lock/my_file_lock:    root      26156 f.... flock
                           root      26157 f.... hourly.sh
                           root      26159 f.... npm
                           root      26225 f.... npm
                           root      26328 f.... npm
                           root      26470 f.... npm

root@host:/ fuser -k /var/lock/my_file_lock 
/run/lock/my_file_lock:     4121  4122  4124  4153  4290  4430

root@host:/ ps -ef
COMMAND  PID USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
...
root      4134     1  0 14:51 ?        00:00:00 sh -c node long_running_script.js
root      4135  4134  0 14:51 ?        00:00:08 node long_running_script.js
```

Comment: I don't at all advise using `cron` for this purpose, by the way -- not what it's made for, not what it's good at, and there are more appropriate tools for the job. Which process supervision system does your OS ship with? (Even ancient SysV init can do process supervision, in that case via `/etc/inittab`; by contrast, that job is much more effectively done by upstart, daemontools, systemd, runit, etc etc).

Comment: BTW, `NPM="/usr/bin/npm"` and then using `$NPM` is an antipattern. There's no actual compelling reason to use that practice, and plenty of reasons not to.

Comment: Good point, probably subject to a different question. Admittedly, I know nothing of process supervision systems; this is all running in a Ubuntu Xenial based system.

Comment: Hmm. Ubuntu used to run upstart and then switched to systemd -- it should be one of the two. If you set up a service with one or the other, you can configure *that* to be responsible for running your script, restarting it when it fails, and cleaning up stray processes.

Comment: ...btw, inasmuch as this is a very specific piece of software that goes out of its way to evade the technique you're using, it might be worth amending the question to make that software an explicit part of it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about the anti-pattern. I typically do that to cope with cron's environment being capricious with its $PATH. If I am understanding you correctly, you think that this is likely npm's fault?

Comment: With respect to the PATH, you can (and should) set that in your crontab. `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin` or such at the very top of the crontab will apply to all jobs therein.

Comment: Hmm. Well, **that's** interesting -- it's showing that the lock file really was inherited. `fuser -k` really should have succeeded in the kill... unless it itself is *also* holding the lock file, and killed itself first. :)

Comment: If you add `-v` to the `fuser` command, does it show that it's finding the npm command?

Comment: It appears that it does find npm but npm's call to `sh -c` is where fuser stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139105/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-omtinez).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `fuser -k` to kill all processes having your lockfile open:

```
fuser -k /var/lock/my_lock_file
```

---

That said, Node quite intentionally tries not to pass file descriptors through to child processes. Since you're using NPM, you might try reusing a file descriptor that's going to be passed through anyhow. For instance, to use stdin:

```
exec 0<>/var/lock/my_lock_file
flock -x 0 || exit
# ...put the rest of your code here...
```

will pass in the lock on stdin, so as long as your original stdin is passed through to subprocesses, those processes should inherit the lock and be killed by `fuser`.

If stdin, stdout or stderr is *not* passed through, I would suggest chatting with upstream for the specific tooling or process that isn't passing it through to see if there's a way to avoid or modify that behavior.

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, and it only kills the shell; not the sub-processes and their children.

Comment: Interesting. Is npm closing file descriptors it inherits? (I'd suggest looking at the FD table in procfs while the service is running).

Comment: (to be clear, a program has to go out of its way not to inherit a FD, and thus the lock; it's worth figuring out just where that's happening).

Comment: BTW, I'm having connectivity issues here -- half my comments aren't going through.

Comment: Updated the original question with more information, the output of `ps -ef`, `lsof`.